# When i need to to stop dividing octants in Octree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, cg, octree

I'm implementing octree data structure. In octants i store triangles. So question: When i need to to stop dividing octants in Octree? I think about max depth or number of max number of triangles in octant, but how i can calculate this values?

Comment: You cannot calculate these values, you need to try out what works best for a given dataset. Good starting values are "10" for entries per octant and maybe 10 or 20 for depth.
For depth there is a max limit given by the precision of your coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good rule for many circumstances is to subdivide a box if the number of triangles in it is more than twice its depth in the tree.  This ensures that:

1. The total space consumed by the tree is at most proportional to the number of trianges;
2. The total time spent traversing down the tree is at most proportional to the number of triangles you'll have to directly process in the target leaf; and
3. You can still go deep when necessary to decompose a tight cluster.